How do i get my cart-btn to start working?
In the navbar, I have a cart button that is supposed to toggle open when it is clicked on and close when the close button is clicked on. For some reason, it isn't working.
I created an .active class in the CSS styling and I used querySelector() to get the #cart-btn id and the .close class as well. I tried to add the cart-item-container class when the cart-btn is clicked and remove it when the close button is clicked on


let shoppingcart = document.querySelector('.cart-items-container');

document.querySelector('#cart-btn').onclick = () => {
  shoppingcart.classList.add('active');
}

document.querySelector('.close').onclick = () => {
  shoppingcart.classList.remove('active');
}
header .icons #cart-btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 70px;
}

header .icons #cart-btn .totalQuantity {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #b31010;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: var(--white);
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}

header .cart-items-container {
  color: var(--light-black);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: var(--white);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: right 1s;
}

header .cart-items-container .active {
  right: 0;
}
<div class="icons">
  <div class="iconCart">
    <div id="cart-btn" class='bx bx-shopping-bag'>
      <div class="totalQuantity">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="account-btn" class='bx bx-user'></div>
  <div id="menu-btn" class='bx bx-menu'></div>
</div>

<!--SHOPPING CART-->
<div class="cart-items-container">
  <!--div id="close" class='bx bx-x'></div-->
  <h2>CART</h2>
  <div class="listCart">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/shop-3.png" alt="">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="name">
          Product Name
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          $50/1 product
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quantity">
        <button>-</button>
        <span class="value">3</span>
        <button>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="close">CLOSE</div>
    <div class="checkout">
      <a href="checkout.html">CHECKOUT</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




What's the actual problem? Clicking on the #cart-btn "button" does add the class active and clicking on the close "button" removes the class

At first, you should start to actually use buttons. Not that onclick is a single event that will overwrite each other as you can only have 1. A good start would be to use addEventListener instead to append events instead of replacing them.

You need to hide the cart contents using the :not() selector. Here's a working version:
Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8dam2769/3/
Snippet:


let shoppingcart = document.querySelector('.cart-items-container');

document.querySelector('#cart-btn').onclick = () => {
  shoppingcart.classList.add('active');
}

document.querySelector('.close').onclick = () => {
  shoppingcart.classList.remove('active');
}
.icons #cart-btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icons #cart-btn .totalQuantity {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #b31010;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: var(--white);
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}

.cart-items-container {
  color: var(--light-black);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: var(--white);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: right 1s;
}

.cart-items-container.active {
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}
.cart-items-container:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
<div class="icons">
  <div class="iconCart">
    <div id="cart-btn" class='bx bx-shopping-bag'>
      <div class="totalQuantity">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="account-btn" class='bx bx-user'></div>
  <div id="menu-btn" class='bx bx-menu'></div>
</div>

<!--SHOPPING CART-->
<div class="cart-items-container">
  <!--div id="close" class='bx bx-x'></div-->
  <h2>CART</h2>
  <div class="listCart">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/shop-3.png" alt="">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="name">
          Product Name
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          $50/1 product
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quantity">
        <button>-</button>
        <span class="value">3</span>
        <button>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="close">CLOSE</div>
    <div class="checkout">
      <a href="checkout.html">CHECKOUT</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




This code achieves the behavoiur you expected.
Just the open button seems out of place there, so perhaps this is where you get lost.
Try writing your buttons as following:
<div class="buttons">
    <div id="cart-btn">OPEN</div>
    <div class="close">CLOSE</div>
    <div class="checkout">
      <a href="checkout.html">CHECKOUT</a>
    </div>
 </div>


How would this solve the issue OP is experiencing? As pointed out in the comment, the snippet works as is and OP has to provide more details on the actual problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
